# C# Check Task status

Tags: c#, task

I use one minute timer to create task which call everytime same procedure but with some parameter value (different but could be same as some prevoius) and I would like to check before create the task if exist any task called procedure with current parametr value. If not then create the task and if yes then do nothing (waiting for finnish the task).

In timer:

```
// Check if exist Task called MyProcedure with current myParameter value.
// If NO then

   Task task = new Task(() => { MyProcedure(myParameter); });
   task.Start();

// else nothing
```

Comment: [Do not use `Task` constructors](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2014/05/a-tour-of-task-part-1-constructors.html).

Comment: It sounds like maybe some `ConcurrentDictionary<TYourParameter, Task>` would work here, keyed by `myParameter`, no?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like:

```cs
private readonly ConcurrentDictionary<SomeType, Task> _tasks = new();

Task DoTheThing(SomeType value) => _tasks.GetOrAdd(value,
    static myParameter => Task.Run(() => MyProcedure(myParameter)));
```

Comment: That's the right solution ;-) Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

It's not so easy to verify if a certain method has been called.
But what you con do is to work on a List of your tasks created.

```
// create a list of type Task
List<Task> tasks = new List<Task>();
    
// run the Task and add it to your list
tasks.Add(Task.Run(() => Method()));        
    
    // exmaple: get the recently added task
var t = tasks[tasks.Count - 1];
            
if (t.IsCompleted == false){
    Console.WriteLine("task is running");
}
    
t.Wait(); // wait for this explicit task
if (t.IsCompleted){
    Console.WriteLine("task is comleted");
}
```